# Regex optional groups

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to capture up to four groups of text between `<p>` and `</p>`. I can do that using the following regex: 
`<h5>Trivia<\/h5><p>(.*)<\/p><p>(.*)<\/p><p>(.*)<\/p><p>(.*)<\/p>`

The text to match on:

`<h5>Trivia</h5><p>Was discovered by a freelance photographer while sunbathing on Bournemouth Beach in August 2003.</p><p>Supports Southampton FC.</p><p>She has 11 GCSEs and 2 'A' Levels.</p><p>Listens to soul, R&amp;B, <a href="/name/nm0005567/">Stevie Wonder</a>, <a href="/name/nm0291349/">Aretha Franklin</a>, <a href="/name/nm0713378/">Usher Raymond</a>, <a href="/name/nm0001391/">Michael Jackson</a> and <a href="/name/nm0584117/">George Michael</a>.</p>`

It outputs the four lines of text. It also works as intended if there are more trivia items or  `<p>` occurrences.

But if there are less than 4 trivia items or `<p>` groups, it outputs nothing since it cannot find the fourth group. How do I make that group optional?

I've tried: `<h5>Trivia<\/h5><p>(.*?)<\/p>(?:<p>(.*?)<\/p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)<\/p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)<\/p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)<\/p>)?` and that works according to http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but it doesn't work if I put it inside PHP code. It only detects one group and puts everything in it.

Comment: Which delimiter are you using? Cause you didn't escape the `/`es in the last regex. No obvious reason why the optionality approach shouldn't workhere. -- Also, while I'm not trying to witter on the dated meme, this might be simpler with HTML/DOM traversal than a regex (though sufficient for this case and if your input is mediocrely coherent). But see phpQuery or QueryPath for simplicity, or raw DOM methods if too much spare time.

Comment: I mistakenly left out the /'s in the last regex (sampling the regex I actually tried). Edited those in for clarity. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic word is either 'escaping' or 'delimiters', read on.

The first regex:
`<h5>Trivia<\/h5><p>(.*)<\/p><p>(.*)<\/p><p>(.*)<\/p><p>(.*)<\/p>`
worked because you escaped the `/` characters in tags like `</h5>` to `<\/h5>`.

But in your second regex (correctly enclosing each paragraph in a optional non-capturing group, fetching 1 to 5 paragraphs):
`<h5>Trivia</h5><p>(.*?)</p>(?:<p>(.*?)</p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)</p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)</p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)</p>)?`
you forgot to escape those `/` characters.
It should then have been:
`$pattern = '/<h5>Trivia<\/h5><p>(.*?)<\/p>(?:<p>(.*?)<\/p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)<\/p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)<\/p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)<\/p>)?/';`

The above is assuming you were putting your regex between two `/` "delimiters" characters (out of conventional habit).

To dive a little deeper into the rabbit-hole, one should note that in php the first and last character of a regular expression is usually a "[delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)", so one can add modifiers at the end (like case-insensitive etc).

So instead of escaping your regex, you could also use a `~` character (or `#`, etc) as a delimiter.
Thus you could also use the same identical (second) regex that you posted and enclose for example like this:
`$pattern = '~<h5>Trivia</h5><p>(.*?)</p>(?:<p>(.*?)</p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)</p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)</p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)</p>)?~';`

Here is a working (web-based) [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/52d82a66f50e955f9000d30576c7f9f5f73eec56) of that, using `#` as delimiter (just because we can).

Comment: Your last fiddle did the trick using # as a delimeter in combination with $pattern instead of // (what I originally used in my preg_match). Thanks for the additional info and answer! The other combinations either reported an undefined offset or concatenated all groups in [0].

Answer (score 1):

You can use the question mark to make each `<p>...</p>` optional:

```
$pattern = '~<h5>Trivia</h5>(?:<p>(.*?)</p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)</p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)</p>)?(?:<p>(.*?)</p>)?~';
```

Use the Dom is a good option too.

Comment: You say: '*You can use the question mark to make each <p>...</p> optional*'. The asker already did this (correctly enclosing the paragraphs in a optional non-capturing group) in his second regex (with the difference: his regex searches for a non-optional first paragraph followed by 4 optional paragraphs). So whilst your code works, it does not explain *why*. However +1 for hinting at better solutions instead of regexing tag-soup.